# For each linear transformation A on an n-dimensional vector space there exists a linear transformation B such that AB=0 and ρ(A)+ρ(B)=n

Tags: linear-algebra

From Halmos Linear Algebra:

For each linear transformation $A$ on an $n$-dimensional vector space there exists a linear transformation $B$ such that $AB=0$ and such that $\rho(A)+\rho(B)=n$.

I know that if $AB=0$, then $\rho(A)+\rho(B) \le n$. I am having trouble proving that there must exist a $B$ such that $AB=0$ and how to go from that to $\rho(A)+\rho(B)=n$. I think I have to assume that $\rho(B)=v(A)$ and determine the $B$ accordingly, but lost on how to do so.

Comment: What do you mean with $\rho$ and $v$?

Comment: $\rho$ being the rank and $v$ the nullity

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $\rho$ must mean rank.

Hint: Find a $B$ whose range is  the null space of $A$.